# How do I make 1 "oninput" field yield multiple "output" fields?

Tags: javascript, html, output

What I mean is, I want someone to be able to enter a number into an input box, and it have it yield a range. So if they enter the number `2`, it shows an output of `2*300-2*400 (600-800)`.

I have been using

```
 <form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(300)">

 <input type="text" name="a" value="">

 <output name="x" for="a b"></output>
```

However that only yields the `variable*300`. How do I get a second output box directly after the first with the `variable*400`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<form oninput="x.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(300);y.value=parseInt(a.value)*parseInt(400);">

<input type="text" name="a" value="">

<output name="x" for="a b"></output>
<output name="y" for="a b"></output>
```

Comment: Well thanks, that was definitely simple enough. I tried so many variations of that but I guess just beat around the right answer.!